# Specific Akka UseCase

Tags: akka

I have a specific use-case for an `Akka` implementation.

I have a set of agents who send heartbeats to Akka. Akka takes this heartbeat, and assigns actors to send them to my meta-data server (a separate server). This part is done.

Now my meta-data server also needs to send action information to the agents. However, since these agents may be behind firewalls, Akka cannot communicate to them directly so it needs to send the action as a response to the Heartbeat. Thus when the meta-data server sends an action Akka stores it in a `DurableMessageQueue` (separate one for each `agentID`) and keeps the mapping of agent-ID to `DurableMessageQueue` in a `HashMap`. Then whenever the heartbeat comes, before responding it checks this queue and piggybacks the action in the response.

The issue with this is that the `HashMap` will be in a single JVM and therefor I cannot scale this. Am I missing something or is there a better way to do it?

I have Akka running behind Mina server running which received and sends messages.

Comment: I'm confused about one detail here.  You say that the agents are sending heartbeats and that there is a response to the heartbeat.  How are the agents sending the heartbeats?  Are you using Akka to do this via `ask` (`?`) or some other protocol (i.e. http)?  I'm only asking because if you are using `ask`, then the response is not truly a request/response and the responding actor will need to be able to "see" the originator (no firewall blocking traffic) in order to send a response back to it.

Comment: The heartbeat comes via https protocol and hots the Mina server. This is then handled by Akka.

Comment: If you want to stick with this approach and want to be able to support more than one JVM, you could look into externalizing the actions in something like memcached/couchbase or redis.  The key would be the agent id and the value for redis could be a list of actions.  If memcached, it could be a string that is atomically appended to.  When the pickup occurs, you clear that key so nothing to pickup for next heartbeat.